# Washing of an IC

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, pcb-assembly, production, washing

Can someone tell me what is the information regarding the process of washing the device during production?

This question is with respect to the [Microchip LAN8741A](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/LAN8741A)

Comment: Are you talking about washing solder flush off? ICs normally go straight from the reel to the board during production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microchip forum response to a [similar question](https://microchipsupport.force.com/s/article/Cleaning-recommendations-for-Serial-EEPROM) is

> Our parts don't have any specific requirements and any
> industry-standard cleaning procedures are acceptable.

There is also nothing shown on the [package data](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/32L_VQFN_5x5x0_9mm_MQ_C04160B_SMSCLegacySQFN.pdf) for this particular package or in [AN233](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/00233D.pdf).

Comment: Could you please share the link of the Microchip forum response/